# Versioning of packages within a Mono Repo

Tags: reactjs, monorepo, turborepo

We currently have a React app (App 1) in a single repository. Soon we need to build a second React app (App 2) where we actually want to reuse a lot of components and code from App1.

I have been looking at various solutions for this and in doing so, setting up a Mono Repo where we have our two apps + some shared libraries seemed like the best idea and easiest to set up.

However, now that I am looking into mono repo's it seems that if you update a shared library version, you are actually directly affecting all your applications that you have in this mono repo. This is something we want to have control over ourselves. Our app 1 is in fact an app that we want to deploy more often than our app 2. Can we use 2 different versions of 1 shared library in our 2 apps? And is a Mono Repo even a good solution for doing this?

The tools I have been looking at right now are Nx and TurboRepo.